# Differences in File Reading Netbeans and Intellij. (Extra unknown character)

Tags: java, netbeans, intellij-idea

I didn't notice this until I started playing around on CodeEval and got to the MineSweeper challenge, kept getting failed when I knew the code worked. So I started digging around and trying new things until after hours of writing and rewriting I decided to try a different IDE, I started with Intellij,so I switched over to Netbeans and found that when reading a file, it adds an extra character to the front e.g.

1. Netbeans:[, X][X, X][X, X] and an unread X if I'm using a for loop.
2. Intellij:[X, X][X, X][X, X]

But the character doesn't show up if I print out just the string. I used the same exact .txt file for testing with Intellij in Java and IDLE in Python. They both got the same result but if I use Netbeans or submit to CodeEval I have to account for the extra unknown character. Any Idea why?

The only difference in the code for Netbeans is I used the entire file path to the same file.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Dylan
 */
public class StackOverflow {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("Files/matrix")));
        String line, content = "", MN[], prematrix[], matrix[][], temp[], temps, temp3[], AllMines = "";
        int m, n, Xm, Ym, k, count, firstCount = 0;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            content += line + "Dylan";
            firstCount++;
        }
        temp3 = content.split("Dylan");
        count = temp3.length;
        for (int q = 0; q < count; q++) {
            prematrix = new String[firstCount];
            prematrix[0] = temp3[q];
            temp = prematrix[0].split(";");
            temps = temp[0];
            MN = temps.split(",");
            temps = temp[1];
            prematrix = temps.split("");
            m = Integer.parseInt(MN[0]);//3
            n = Integer.parseInt(MN[1]);//5
            matrix = new String[m][n];
            k = 0;

            //Populates Minefield
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                    matrix[i][j] = prematrix[k];
                    k++;
                }
            }
            //Gets max X,Y
            Xm = n - 1;
            Ym = m - 1;
            /*A matrix to match the Minefield.
            Number of touch mines will be added here*/
            int[][] mines = new int[m][n];
            for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                Arrays.fill(mines[i], 0);
            }
            //Double for loop to check how many mines
            // the position is touching
            for (int y = 0; y < m; y++) {
                for (int x = 0; x < n; x++) {
                    if (!matrix[y][x].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                        if (x != Xm && y != 0) {
                            if (matrix[y - 1][x + 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != Xm && y != Ym) {
                            if (matrix[y + 1][x + 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != 0 && y != Ym) {
                            if (matrix[y + 1][x - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                            if (matrix[y - 1][x - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }
                        if (x != 0 && x != Xm) {
                            if (matrix[y][x + 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                            if (matrix[y][x - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (x == 0) {
                            if (matrix[y][x + 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (y == 0) {
                            if (matrix[y + 1][x].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (x == Xm) {
                            if (matrix[y][x - 1].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }

                        if (y != Ym && y != 0) {
                            if (matrix[y - 1][x].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;

                            }
                            if (matrix[y + 1][x].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;

                            }
                        }
                        if (y == Ym) {
                            if (matrix[y - 1][x].equalsIgnoreCase("*")) {
                                mines[y][x]++;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        mines[y][x] = -1;
                    }
                }
            }
            String mineS = "";
            for (int[] p : mines) {
                mineS += Arrays.toString(p);
            }
            mineS = mineS.replace("-1", "*").replace(",", "").replace("]", "").replace("[", "").replace(" ", "");
            System.out.println(mineS);
            AllMines += mineS + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(AllMines);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds a bit unlikely, although of course we'll never know what's going on as long as you don't provide any code to examine.

Comment: Alright it's up now. I just tested it, some exact code copied and pasted and still a difference. But the code doesn't matter I can write a new class that reads a file and both still show a one character difference.